# type '(dynamic) => NotificationModel?' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => NotificationModel' of 'f'

Tags: flutter, converters

This code is having problem when I build my app. It can't convert datas in first run but after I restart the app, this part works fine. I don't get it.

```
List<T>? fromJsonList(dynamic jsonList) {
    try {
      return jsonList?.map<T>((dynamic json) => fromJson(json))?.toList();
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint("fromJsonList_Err: ${e.toString()}");
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Make sure `fromJson` return `T` not `T?`

Comment: it does return T.